# Relation between 1D and 3D partition function

Tags: solid-state-physics, partition-function

In a solid state physics text author said $$Z_{3D} = [ Z_{1D} ]^{3} $$ $$<E_{3D}>=3<E_{1D}>$$
Where $Z$ is partition function. Can anyone convince me why it is so?

Comment: Which text? And what exactly do you mean with the notation $Z_{nD}$?

Comment: The oxford solid state basics

Comment: $Z$ is partition function.

Comment: Sometimes I think users of physics stackexchange are not co-operative. If you downvote my question you should give me a reason or suggestion. I am open to critique. I demand moderator attention. @Qmechanic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably (you should really give more details when posting questions, so that those without your book can still help you) came across this in the [Einstein model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid) of the harmonic oscillators for the heat capacity estimation, in which case the energy eigenvalues in 1D (say for x-component) are given by:

$$
E_{nx} =\hbar \omega (1/2+n_x)
$$
With $n_x\ge 0$ we know all the possible energy states of the system, so the partition function is simply given by (sum of the weight of each state):

$$
Z_{1D} = \sum e^{-\beta E_{nx}} = \sum \exp{-\beta \hbar \omega (1/2+n)}
$$

In 3D, $E_n$ is given by:

$$
E_{nx,ny,nz} = \hbar \omega \left((1/2+n_x)+(1/2+n_y)+(1/2+n_z)\right)
$$
Substitute the above in the partition function expression again, with $n_x=n_y=n_z=n$:

$$
Z_{3D} = \sum \exp{-\beta \hbar \omega (3/2+3n)}=Z_{1D}^3
$$
As for the average of the energy $E,$ it is really straighforward to show for 3D once you've solved the 1D case (replace $Z$ by $Z_{1D}$):
$$
\langle E \rangle  = -\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta}=...
$$
It is rather trivial from here, so I leave the rest up to you, or simply read your book more carefully, as I know [Steve H. Simon's book](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/book.html) is really well contained.

---

An edit to include a discussion from comments:

> Self-Made Man: Does it also hold for the classical Einstein solid?

Yes, because to solve $Z=\int d\mathbf{p}\int d\mathbf{r}\exp(-\beta\mathcal{H}(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{r}))$ for the Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator, you have $6$ independent Gaussian integrals to solve, specifically because $\mathcal{H}\propto \mathbf{p}^2+\mathbf{r}^2$, so just solve the 1D case, which should give you $2\pi/\beta \left(\frac{m}{k}\right)^{1/2}$, and you will straightforwardly find for the 3D case that $Z_{3D}\propto \left(\frac{m}{k}\right)^{3/2}$ hence the same relation $Z_{3D}=Z_{1D}^3$ is obtained, I have not done the calculations exactly, so I have not included all constants and coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I would try to be comprehensive in future.

Comment: @Self-MadeMan No worries.

Comment: $$d \vec{P}=d p_{x} \hat{i} +d p_{y}  \hat{j}+d p_{z} \hat{k}$$ and $$d \vec{r}=d x \hat{i} +d y \hat{j}+d z \hat{k}$$ will be replaced by $$d \vec{p}$$ and $$d \vec{r}$$ ?

Comment: You will do the integrals component-wise, i.e. $\int d\mathbf{p} \to \int dp_x \int dp_y \int dp_z$ and similarly for the integration over $d\mathbf{r}.$